# Invoke method by socket

Tags: java, sockets

How to invoke a method on the server from client? I'm using java socket. I am able to send and receive messages, but do not know how to invoke methods.
Should I use switch(case)? If text equal name of the method, run this method.
What is the correct/best way?

Comment: Just in case: [Java RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html), the canonical way of remote method invocation.

Comment: A typical way to invoke server code from a client is a Web server. You could tap on some ideas from the way a Web application works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send some messages to the server. The server should then decide based on the message received which method to invoke. E.g. if it gets `"message1"`, it could call `method1`, if it gets `"message2"`, it could call `method2`. Yes, you can use a switch statement for this. The messages do not need to be strings, they could be numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use an *Opcode* that correspond to your methods and then Switch on it.

Easier to maintain then handling the method names directly

Comment: Hello, no I think your mistaken me for someone else.